# Radar chart inside a table for multiple users React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to construct radar charts for team members to check how they are contributing for a project, so for members, I want to create a radar chart that shows the various field. The idea is to construct the data inside a table corresponding to each team member - but I am always getting empty charts.
The data for the the same is somewhat like:

```
    Data:[
    {name: 'ABC', gitCommit: '200', gitPull: '3', jira: '4', slack: '5', confluence: '6'},
     {name: 'XYZ', gitCommit: '200', gitPull: '3', jira: '4', slack: '5', confluence: '6'}
    ]
```

I have created a table:

```
    <table id='projects' className="zebra" data-sortable="">
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>{this.renderChartHeader()}</tr>
                                    {this.renderChart()}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

and upon renderChart the below is being called:

```
    renderChart(){
            return this.state.Data.map((Data, index) => {
                return(
                    <tr key={Data.name}>
                    <td>{Data.name}</td>
                    <td>
                    <RadarChart cx={300} cy={250} outerRadius={150} width={500} height={500} data={Data}>
                        <PolarGrid gridType='circle'/>
                        <PolarAngleAxis dataKey="name" />
                        <PolarRadiusAxis angle={30} domain={[0, 10]} />
                        <Radar name="Sara" dataKey="jira" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" fillOpacity={0.6} />
                        <Legend />
                    </RadarChart>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })
        }
```

The idea is to have a table to look like this:

[Table with a member name and corresponding radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H43n.png)

Edited
Added the full version of the code
Within this code the handleSubmit will be used when we click on a button and it will populate data from an Backend API - the Data variable will be populated - but for now I am trying with hardcoded values in the Data variable.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import uomHeader from '../header/uomheader.js';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { userActions } from '../_actions';
    import { storeGet } from '../_helpers/helper-funcs.js';
    import BarChart from 'react-bar-chart';
    import {
        Radar, RadarChart, PolarGrid, Legend,
        PolarAngleAxis, PolarRadiusAxis,
      } from 'recharts';
    // import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
    // import {
    //     Chart,
    //     BarSeries,
    //     Title,
    //     ArgumentAxis,
    //     ValueAxis,
    //   } from '@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui';
    // import { Animation } from '@devexpress/dx-react-chart';
    const team = 1;
    const teamName = "SWEN90013-2020-SP";
    const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    
    class IndividualContributionPage extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                
                projectName: '',
                submitted: false,
                total: [
                    {student_id:'', fullname:''}
                ],
                // The Array to store the data
                Data:[
    
                    {name: 'ABC', gitCommit: '200', gitPull: '3', jira: '4', slack: '5', confluence: '6'},
                    {name: 'XYZ', gitCommit: '200', gitPull: '3', jira: '4', slack: '5', confluence: '6'},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},
                    // {name: '', gitCommit: '', gitPull: '', jira: '', slack: '', confluence: ''},            
                ],
               
            }
    
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    
        }
    
        handleChange(e) {
            
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            this.setState({ [name]: value });
        }
    
    
        handleSubmit(e) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
            const { projectName} = this.state;
    
            this.props.getTeamList(team);
            this.setState({ submitted: true });
            
            if(storeGet("teamList")!=null){
                for(var i in storeGet("teamList")){
                    // Get the member's configuration
    
                    this.props.getMemberConfiguration(projectName,storeGet("teamList")[i].student_id);
                    console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
                    console.log(storeGet("memberConfig"));
    
                    // Get the full name
                    this.state.Data[i].name = storeGet("teamList")[i].fullname;
                    console.log(this.state.Data[i].name);
    
                    //Get SLACK - need User ID
                    this.props.getSlackUser(team, storeGet("teamList")[i].student_id);
                    //Get JIRA data - need User ID
                    this.props.getJiraUser(teamName, storeGet("teamList")[i].student_id);
    
                    // TODO
                    // Get Git Data - need Git Username, currently hardcoded
                    this.props.codeCommitsPerMember(projectName, "zhanglihuan");
                    // TODO
                    //Get Conflunece Data - need Username, currently hardcoded
                    this.props.numPagesPerMember("yujuzhang");
    
            
                    if(storeGet("commitsPerMember")!=null){
                        this.state.Data[i].gitCommit = storeGet("commitsPerMember").total;
                        // TODO: No pull request in the return value, so using the file_changed in temporary
                        this.state.Data[i].gitPull = storeGet("commitsPerMember").file_changed;
                    }
    
    
                    // console.log(this.state.Data[i].gitCommit);
                    // console.log(this.state.Data[i].gitPull);
    
                    if(storeGet("slackUser")!=null){
                        this.state.Data[i].slack = storeGet("slackUser")['total_number'];
                    }
                    // if(storeGet("jiraUser")!=null){
                    //     this.props.Data[i].jira = storeGet("jiraUser")['count_issues_done'];
                    // }
                    // console.log(storeGet("numPagesPerMember"));
                    // if(storeGet("numPagesPerMember")!=null){
                    //     this.props.Data[i].confluence = storeGet("numPagesPerMember");
                    // }
                   
                }
                    
            }
    
    
    
        }
        
        render() {
            const {submitted} = this.state;
    
            return (
                <div className="uomcontent">
                    {uomHeader("Individual Contribution Page")}
                    <div role="main">
                        <div className="page-inner">
                            <form name="form">   
                                <div>
                                    <a className="button cta" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >Fetch</a>
                                </div>
                                {submitted && 
                                <table id='projects' className="zebra" data-sortable="">
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>{this.renderChartHeader()}</tr>
                                    {this.renderChart()}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>   
                                }
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    
        renderChartHeader() {
            let header = ['Student Name', 'Radar Chart'];
            return header.map((key, index) => {
                return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
            })
          
        }
        
        renderChart(){
            return this.state.Data.map((Data, index) => {
                return(
                    <tr key={Data.name}>
                    <td>{Data.name}</td>
                    <td>
                    <RadarChart cx={300} cy={250} outerRadius={150} width={500} height={500} data={Data}>
                        <PolarGrid gridType='circle'/>
                        <PolarAngleAxis dataKey="name" />
                        <PolarRadiusAxis angle={30} domain={[0, 10]} />
                        <Radar name="ABC" dataKey="jira" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" fillOpacity={0.6} />
                        <Legend />
                    </RadarChart>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })
        }
    
        
    
    }
    
    function mapState(state) {
        
        const { projectName } = state;
        return { projectName };
    }
    
    const actionCreators = {
        loginGit: userActions.loginGit,
        totalCodeCommits: userActions.totalCodeCommits,
        codeCommitsPerMember: userActions.codeCommitsPerMember,
        AllPagesOnConfluence: userActions.AllPagesOnConfluence,
        getTeamList: userActions.getTeamList,
        getMemberConfiguration: userActions.getMemberConfiguration,
        getSlackUser: userActions.getSlackUser,
        getJiraUser: userActions.getJiraUser,
        numPagesPerMember: userActions.numPagesPerMember,
    };
    
    
    const Product = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(IndividualContributionPage);
    export { Product as IndividualContributionPage };
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducable version, as I can't find logical mistakes in your code

Comment: Thanks Moaaz for your reply, I have added the full version

Comment: For future questions, please consider using https://codesandbox.io/ to provide a sample of your code that includes your issue, so we can better help u. Good luck!

Comment: Yes surely Moaaz, I will keep that in mind. Also I was wondering if we can use a doughnut (donut) chart instead of a radar chart in this, and if so how would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
<RadarChart cx={300} cy={250} outerRadius={150} width={500} height={500} data={Data}>
```

Specifically in `data` prop. It should recieve the whole array of objects (`this.state.Data`), but your `Data` here refers to only one object dut to the `map` function.

This should solve your problem:

```js
data={this.state.Data}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-moser-q74t4?file=/src/Chart.js)

Comment: it works! great thank you. I had one more doubt, as you can see the data format I have. Now if I want to plot the radar chart for Just ABC and then XYZ separately - showing the gitCommit, jira, etc. in the radar chart - how do I supply the datakey in this case?

Comment: @AvijitChauhan Added another answer

Answer (score 0):

**Separate charts:**
**First:** you will need t re-structure your data:

```js
  Data: [
        {
          name: "Git commits",
          A: 50,
          B: 100,
          C: 150
        },
        {
          name: "Git pull",
          A: 10,
          B: 20,
          C: 30
        },
        {
          name: "Slack",
          A: 20,
          B: 40,
          C: 80
        }
      ]
    };
```

where A, B, and C are different levels of contribution for each platform,

**Second:** You will need to create an array for the contributers' names and scores:

```js
const contributers = [
  { name: "James", score: "A" },
  { name: "Emma", score: "B" }
];
```

**Finally:** use map on this array to create a chart for each:

```js
  renderChart() {
    return contributers.map((contributer) => {
      return (
        <RadarChart
          cx={300}
          cy={250}
          outerRadius={150}
          width={500}
          height={500}
          data={this.state.Data}
        >
          <PolarGrid gridType="circle" />
          <PolarAngleAxis dataKey="name" />
          <PolarRadiusAxis angle={30} domain={[0, 10]} />
          <Radar
            name={contributer.name}
            dataKey={contributer.score}
            stroke="#8884d8"
            fill="#8884d8"
            fillOpacity={0.6}
          />
          <Legend />
        </RadarChart>
      );
    });
  }
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-moser-q74t4?file=/src/Chart.js:1924-2575)

Comment: Thank you so much Moaaz. It really helped. But I was wondering if we can use a doughnut (donut) chart instead of a radar chart in this, and if so how would that be possible?

Comment: Actually, this the first time I work with charts at all :D  
I encourage you to re-check the docs, and google what you need, and I'll be happy to help if you face any issue.